# Tomcat warnings: No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I get strange warnings from Tomcat 7. Everything seems to work great, but I don't wanna get any warnings at all. Tried to google it, but all attempts were in vain. I suppose something is wrong with my spring configuration file.

So here is contents of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Contents of appContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="props"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/logviewer.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourceIS" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${db_driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db_url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${db_user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db_pass}"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="${db_initial_pool_size}"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${db_min_pool_size}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${db_max_pool_size}"/>
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="${db_checkout_timeout}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplateIS" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSourceIS"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="application" class="comtech.logviewer.main.Application">
        <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplateIS"/>
        <property name="root" value="${root}"/>
        <property name="logRowsLimit" value="${log_rows_limit}"/>
        <property name="accessLogDefaultOrderBy" value="${access_log_default_order_by}"/>
        <property name="accessLogDefaultOrderByDirection" value="${access_log_default_order_by_direction}"/>
        <property name="dateFormat" value="${date_format}"/>
        <property name="validLogTimeIntervalSeconds" value="${valid_log_time_interval_seconds}"/>
        <property name="defaultTimeout" value="${default_timeout}"/>
        <property name="newServerResponseTimeout" value="${new_server_response_timeout}"/>
        <property name="dbUrl" value="${db_user}"/>
        <property name="dbUser" value="${db_url}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="updateCacheTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="startDelay" value="${cache_update_delay:0}"/>
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="${cache_update_interval:180000}"/>
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
                <property name="targetObject" ref="application"/>
                <property name="targetMethod" value="updateCache"/>
                <property name="concurrent" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="updateJSTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="startDelay" value="${cache_update_delay:0}"/>
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="${cache_update_interval:180000}"/>
        <property name="jobDetail">
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
                <property name="targetObject" ref="application"/>
                <property name="targetMethod" value="updateJS"/>
                <property name="concurrent" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="updateCacheTrigger"/>
                <ref bean="updateJSTrigger"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Tomcat's output with these warnings:

```
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/list/value'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/list'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/constructor-arg'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/list/ref'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/list/ref'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property/list'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean/property'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans/bean'.
фев 11, 2014 2:12:08 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester endElement
WARNING:   No rules found matching 'beans'.
```

**UPDATE:** server.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**UPDATE 2**
I get these warnings only while deploying with the help of Intellij IDEA, if I manually deploy war file, catalina.out will have no errors or warnings. But I don't get such warnings while deploying other applications in IDEA, so something is still wrong.

Comment: Can you post your server.xml as well. Those warnings are as a result of something wrong in there.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet while building? It can be some missing package that needs to be downloaded. Try to `clean&build`.

Comment: @Desolator I use IntelliJ IDEA as IDE, so all missing packages should be highlighted. I am connected to the internet while building and I even performed Maven->Reimport in Idea, but that doesn't help.

Comment: @KirillSmirnov I highly recommand you to use Netbeans

Comment: Do you have a META-INF/context.xml in your project?

Comment: I'm getting the same warning, which started right after adding some 'context-param' to the 'context.xml' file, which is located in my local directory of the tomcat server installation that I'm using for debug.